# how to change name of header in prestashop

Tags: header, prestashop

I am creating a webshop in PrestaShop. I want to change the name of a header within the page.

I have looked in the webpage files but cant find anywhere where the name is.

I highlighted the name to be changed in yellow:

[image: screenshot]

How can I change this name?

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Answer (score 0):

Go to Translations->Theme translations, select your language.
In the top search input add your searched term e.g."populariausios" and you'll see results containing this term.
It should be in Shop > Theme > Catalog.

Comment: Thank you this helped.Sorry for the long response.

Comment: Glad it did. Maybe you should select it as the accepted reply in order to help others looking for the same.